# `np.array([list,list])` passed to 3D plotter returns empty result

Tags: matplotlib

I'm just trying to generate a 3D surface and a planar contour corresponding to that in the same axes using three lists `x`, `y`, and `apf` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm

class Point(object):

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y

    def distance(self, goal):
        dx = self.X - goal.X
        dy = self.Y - goal.Y
        return math.hypot(dx, dy)

    def move(self, xGrad, yGrad):
        self.X -= xGrad*1e-2
        self.Y -= yGrad*1e-2
        return self

def APF(a, r, currentX, currentY, goalX, goalY, obstacles):
    attr = a*math.hypot(currentX-goalX, currentY-goalY)**2
    repl = 0
    for item in obstacles:
        repl += 1/math.hypot(currentX-item.point.X, currentY-item.point.Y)**2
    repl *= r
    return attr + repl

def gradX(a, r, h, currentX, currentY, goalX, goalY, obstacles):
    num1 = APF(a, r, currentX+h, currentY, goalX, goalY, obstacles)
    num2 = APF(a, r, currentX-h, currentY, goalX, goalY, obstacles)
    return (num1-num2)/(2*h)

def gradY(a, r, h, currentX, currentY, goalX, goalY, obstacles):
    num1 = APF(a, r, currentX, currentY+h, goalX, goalY, obstacles)
    num2 = APF(a, r, currentX, currentY-h, goalX, goalY, obstacles)
    return (num1-num2)/(2*h)

class Obstacle(object):
    def __init__(self, point, radius):
        self.point = point
        self.radius = radius

if __name__== "__main__" :

    start = Point(1.0, 1.0)
    goal = Point(8.0, 8.0)

    p1 = Point(3.0, 3.0)
    p2 = Point(5.0, 6.0)
    p3 = Point(7.0, 6.0)

    obs1 = Obstacle(p1, 0.5)
    obs2 = Obstacle(p2, 0.5)
    obs3 = Obstacle(p3, 0.5)

    obstacles = [obs1, obs2, obs3]
    trajectory = [start]
    trajectory2 = [start]

    h = 10e-4
    a = 0.5
    r = 1
    temp = start
    x = []
    y = []
    apf = []

    max_grad = 0
    i = 0
    maxiter = 1000

    while temp.distance(goal)!=0 and i < maxiter:
        i += 1
        apf.append(APF(a, r, start.X, start.Y, goal.X, goal.Y, obstacles))
        next = temp.move(gradX(a, r, h, start.X, start.Y, goal.X, goal.Y, obstacles),
                         gradY(a, r, h, start.X, start.Y, goal.X, goal.Y, obstacles))
        trajectory.append(next)
        x.append(next.X)
        y.append(next.Y)

g = plt.figure()  
ax2 = g.gca(projection='3d')
ax2.plot_surface(np.array([x,x]), np.array([y,y]), np.array([apf,apf]), rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)
cset = ax2.contourf(np.array([x,x]), np.array([y,y]), np.array([apf,apf]), zdir='z', offset=-100, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax2.set_xlabel('X')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y')
ax2.set_zlabel('apf')

ax2.relim()
ax2.autoscale_view()

plt.show()
```

In particular, I considered `np.array([x,x])`, `np.array([y,y])`, and `np.array([apf,apf]` to pass required 2D numpy arrays to plotter functions. But the result is empty. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: `np.array([y,y])` makes no sense for the y coordinate, because both values are the same - so essentially you would get a line, not a surface. More generally, I don't think it's clear how exactly you want your data to be plotted. If you have three 1D arrays, how should the surface look like?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: The distances between nodes are very trivial because of the abundance of the data. Thus, even a point-wise drawing should look like a surface. Yet, I'm wondering whether or not a real sarface plot would be obtained from this setting of data.

Comment: No, identical points will *never* span a surface. So even if you want to see a line you would need to slightly change one of the values, e.g. `np.array([y,y])+np.array([[0],[.1]])`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I actually want to draw the following 3D points: `(x0,y0,apf0)`, `(x1,y1,apf1)`, ..., `(xn,yn,apfn)`, which are not in a line but scattered in the 3D space.

Comment: To me [they don't look scattered, but really just like a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2CPg.png). Actually you can just plot a scatter, like `ax2.scatter(x,y,apf)` to see the line of dots.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Well, to this is not a straight line, but a piece-wise linear plot. Anyway, it is apparently all I can get out of these three arrays of data. Thanks.

Comment: I never said that the line would be linear. The point is, your data just one point after the other, so there is no way it could form a surface.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Sorry. That was a misunderstanding of mine then.